# java exceptions

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

i have two java classes running on different threads. one class makes a connection to the internet while the other 
class monitors the connection status. i want to throw an IOException incase the class making a connection delays 
while reading server response, at the sametime i dont want to throw an exception if there is some response being read from the Server.

i came up with this code.

my problem is i want to throw an IOException in class NetworkMonitor which will be caught by 
NetworkConnector class which is the main class. however the compiler complains of uncaught exception.

```
  public class NetworkConnector{
  //method that connects to the server to send or read data.
  public String sendData(String url ,String data){
     try{

        //start the monitor before we read the serverResponse
        new NetworkMonitor().startMonitor();

        int read ;
        while ((read = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
           //read data.
           sb.append((char) read);

           //monitor if we are reading from Server if not reading count 10 to 0 and throw IoException. 
           new NetworkMonitor().resetCounter();
        }

     } catch(IOException ex){
        //all IOException should be caught here.
     }

  }
```

}

//class that monitors if there a network activity occuring.

```
  public class NetworkMonitor implements Runnable {

  private final int WAITTIME =10;
  private int counter = WAITTIME;


  public void run(){
     try{

        while(counter > 0){
           //waiting here
           counter--; //decrement counter. 
           Thread.sleep(1000);     
        }

        //when counter is at zero throw iOexception 
        throw new IOException("Failed to get server Response");

     } catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     } catch(IOException e){
        //i want to throw the IOEception here since the exception should 
        //be caught by the networkConnector class not the monitor class but the compiler complains.
        // unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage());

        //throwing another exception type is okay ===>why cant we throw the same type of exception we caught.
         throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage()); 
     }


  }

  //reset the counter if called.
  public void resetCounter(){
     counter = WAITTIME;
  }

  public void startMonitor(){
     Thread t = new Thread(this);
     t.start();
  }
```

}

Comment: Exceptions do not pass between Threads. What you want to do cannot be achieved this easily. Instead, you will have to pass an explicit message between the two thread in case there is an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You have a more basic problems

- an exception thrown in one thread needs to be passed to another thread.  You can use an ExecutorService and a Future to do this.
- to implement your timeout you can use a ScheduledExecutorService.  This will allow you to schedule a delayed and cancellable task.
- an exception thrown in one thread won't unblock a blocking read.  You need to close the connection to unblock it and this will cause an IOException.
- Once you have these in place you can use a Callable instead of a Runnable to throw a checked exception.

Instead of sleeping for 1 second, 10 times. You could just sleep for 10 seconds.

Comment: the reason am sleeping for 1 sec is that the counter is reset each time the client reads something from the server, therefore the wait time should always be 10 to be fair to all reads.

Comment: In that case I would make it `volatile` so this change is visible between threads.

Answer (score 0):

The basic design is flawed. Exceptions don't automatically propagate across thread boundaries.

You should probably look into using non-blocking I/O to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are trying to achieve some kind of communication between two threads. Exceptions are not that elegant solution for that. I would recommend changing your code to accomodate better way of communication with `volatile` and `blocking queues` or `executor service`, `future` etc. One way to achieve this is below:

Create a `LinkedBlockingQueue` in the main class from where you fork these two threads as:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>(
        1);
```

Pass this queue to both the threads. Create a `volatile` member in your network monitor class:

```
volatile boolean isAllowed = true;
```

change your while condition in `NetworkConnector` as

```
while ((read = inputStream.read()) != -1 && networkMonitor.isAllowed()) {
```

In your `NetworkMonitor's` `run` method change the while condition with:

```
while(isAllowed) {
Integer i = blockingQueue.poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
if(i==null) 
  isAllowed = false;
}
```

Inside `NetworkConnector's` `while loop` after `append` add this:

```
blockingQueue.add(1);
```

In essence, we add an integer to the queue; as soon as the monitor threads gets an non-null integer it waits for 10 seconds max. The connector thread has 10 seconds to put an integer on the queue and if it does not its while loop breaks. Once out of the loop, do whatever you need to.

I have **not** run this, this is just an example based on initial thoughts. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

`run()` is an overrided method from `Runnable`. In the runnable interface, there's no checked exception definition, so you couldn't throw checked exception from there. But you can throw `RuntimeException` instead of that.